# .Net Project solution conflict

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, model-view-controller

I have a .Net solution which contains various projects: MVC, WCF, Class Library, etc..,

When I try to publish the WCF application I receive the exception below:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, 
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why is the Razor DLL needed for a WCF application?

Comment: Does the WCF project have reference to the MVC project?

Comment: Whats the 'Project' you see next to the error message in 'Error List' Window?Few things for you to check -
1. Check if there is by any chance Razor reference added to your WCF project 
2. See if WCF project has direct dependency on your MVC (or any Razor using projects)
3. Right click the solution file and check if you have multiple startup projects (particularly, if your MVC project ->  Action -> 'Start') If so, change it to single startup project and set your WCF project and try publishing.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No it is independant project

Comment: Try to clean and re-build the project again. If the problem still exists, we could also use Nuget to eliminate the application package.